# How to change the format of the LCOV report executed by Karma?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, karma-runner, lcov, karma-coverage

I've configured Karma to report the coverage of my JavaScript code. Here is the part of the configuration in the `karma.conf.js` file:

```
coverageReporter: {
  reporters: [
    {
      type: 'html',
      dir: 'build/karma/coverage'
    },
    {
      type: 'lcov',
      dir: 'build/karma/coverage',
      subdir: '.'
    },
    {
      type: 'cobertura',
      dir: 'build/karma/coverage'
    }
  ]
},
```

My `lcov.info` file has the following format:

```
TN:
SF:./app/scripts/app.js
FN:16,(anonymous_1)
FN:26,(anonymous_2)
FNF:2
FNH:1
FNDA:1,(anonymous_1)
FNDA:0,(anonymous_2)
DA:2,1
DA:20,1
DA:29,0
DA:34,0
LF:4
LH:2
BRF:0
BRH:0
end_of_record
```

Unfortunately, [the Sonarqube JavaScript plugin](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-javascript) only considers the lines that start with `SF:`, `DA:` or `BRDA:` (cf [LCOVParser](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-javascript/blob/master/sonar-javascript-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/javascript/lcov/LCOVParser.java)).

Due to that, the LCOV HTML report (made by Istanbul) gives me a higher code coverage than Sonar on the same data.

Is there a way to change the format of the `lcov.info` generated?

---

If I look in [Istanbul code](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/lib/report/lcovonly.js), I can imagine the meaning of the different labels:

- `BRF`, `BRH`, `BRDA` are for **branches**.
- `FN`, `FNF`, `FNH`, `FNDA` are for **functions**.
- `LN`, `LF`, `LH` are for **lines**.
- `*F` is the total, while `*H` is the covered information.

The difference between the Istanbul and Sonar coverage seems to be due to the fact that the latter completely ignores the Functions and Branches coverage.

Any idea to solve that?

Comment: Have you considered using the karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter

Comment: We ran into this as well and then ditched the javascript plugin for running the scripts directly. https://github.com/carsdotcom/gulp-sonar Is a nice plugin to work into your gulpfile. It might not work for every situation but solved this problem for us.

Comment: We had a similar issue where the sonar was expecting an absolute file path to calculate the coverage. Our workaround was to add a build task that modified the lcov.info to add the absolute path prefix on the SF: lines

Comment: Did you make it work? I stuck with the lcov import which could not resolve file path, explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878860/sonarqube-and-lcov-report-could-not-resolve-file-paths

Comment: @claya, It would be helpful if you update the build task details. So I can follow the same to see if it works. We are using team city

Comment: Yeah we also had absolute/relative path issue. So we just added a one-liner "sed" script which fixes paths after tests were ran (and before Sonar).

Comment: Btw, they have already fixed branches: https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/commit/d60a53eefc41f7c6a620b8c8d30a89fa590d0809

Answer (score 4):

You could run a script that does: `cat lcov.info | egrep "^(SF|DA|BRDA):" > lcov.info.new; mv lcov.info.new lcov.info`.

With that I get:

```
SF:./app/scripts/app.js
DA:2,1
DA:20,1
DA:29,0
DA:34,0
```