# sonar-runner lcov report discrepency

Tags: sonar-runner, istanbul, lcov, sonarqube-4.5

SonarQube Community,

When doing an analysis of a Node/JS project the coverage valued reported via istanbul show much different than what gets reported and shows on our SonarQube server.
Our SonarQube server is at 4.5.4
Our sonar-runner version is 2.4
The project generated the following report:

Code coverage report for All files

Statements: 67.65% (1520 / 2247)      Branches: 49.76% (418 / 840)      Functions: 65.13% (269 / 413)      Lines: 68.31% (1481 / 2168)      Ignored: none

File        Statements      Branches        Functions       Lines
classes/        94.4%   (118 / 125) 70% (7 / 10)    100%    (9 / 9) 94.35%  (117 / 124)
helpers/        84% (126 / 150) 75.44%  (43 / 57)   86.67%  (26 / 30)   84.25%  (123 / 146)
services/       82.64%  (976 / 1181)    66.67%  (272 / 408) 81.63%  (160 / 196) 83.26%  (955 / 1147)
view_controllers/       37.93%  (300 / 791) 26.3%   (96 / 365)  41.57%  (74 / 178)  38.08%  (286 / 751)
Generated by istanbul at Tue Sep 15 2015 17:01:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)

The coverage values shown in the SonarQube 4.5.4 drill down differ greatly from what the other report shows: ( I apologize for not being able to post an image but I do not have a high enough reputation yet to do this.)

Technical Debt
64d

Issues
5,707

Blocker    0
 Critical   3
 Major  3,922
 Minor  696
 Info   1,086
Unit Tests Coverage
28.6%
Line Coverage
25.6%
Condition Coverage
49.8%

SQALE Rating
A

Technical Debt Ratio
1.0%
 The project has warnings on the following quality gate conditions: 
Coverage
28.6% < 70.0%
Critical issues
3 > 0
 cd-services-test-Indexing web client cd-services-test-RECORDS-IDX-indexing-web-client
Profiles: Sonar way (JavaScript)

Quality Gate: SonarWayWithFindbugsForNFSWithBuildBreaker - java (Default)

Lines Of Code
104,320

JavaScript

Files
426

Directories
109
Lines
120,238

Functions
6,726

Classes
4
Statements
32,377
Accessors
0
Useless Code
18,260
18,260 lines in duplications
Duplications
41.5%
Lines
49,923
Blocks
10,915
Files
89 
Complexity
4.9 /function 
4.5 /class 
29.5  /file 
Total: 12,588

If you should need the actual lcov.info file or if you would like pngs of the data above to better analyze this problem I can send them via an e-mail directly to you.

What would you suggest I do to try and track down why there is such a discrepency?

Any thoughts on how I can proceed to get correct data logged would be very much appreciated.

Doug

Comment: I believe this may be the same thing as was asked in the question " How to change the format of the LCOV report executed by Karma?" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806209/how-to-change-the-format-of-the-lcov-report-executed-by-karma