# SonarQube not reading javascript test coverage from lcov

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, code-coverage, lcov, karma-coverage

I'm working on integrating Karma tests in maven and using SonarQube for test coverage reporting.

While i'm able to view HTML karma test coverage reports(coverage type HTML in `karma.conf.js`), i'm not able to view the results in SonarQube when the type is lcov in `karma.conf.js`.

Content of `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <sonar.language>js</sonar.language>
    <sonar.exclusions>src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibs/${apps.project.path}/js/vendor/**</sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibs/${apps.project.path}/karma_target/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>
</properties>



<build>
    <!-- Karma test sonar coverage properties: Start-->   
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibs/${apps.project.path}/js</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibs/${apps.project.path}/js_test</testSourceDirectory>
```

When i run `mvn clean install sonar:sonar` it creates lcov.info file in the `<sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>` mentioned in the properties.

Content of `lcov.info` file:

```
TN:
SF:D:\Workspace\Workspace_MasterCard\Issuer_53\loyalty\aem\loyalty-aem-web\trunk\loyalty-aem-web-ui\src\main\content\jcr_root\etc\clientlibs\loyalty\js\config\namespace.js
FN:15,(anonymous_1)
FNF:1
FNH:1
FNDA:5,(anonymous_1)
DA:2,1
DA:15,1
DA:17,5
DA:21,5
DA:22,0
DA:25,5
DA:28,8
DA:30,5
DA:33,8
DA:36,5
LF:10
LH:9
BRDA:2,1,0,1
BRDA:2,1,1,1
BRDA:21,2,0,0
BRDA:21,2,1,5
BRDA:28,3,0,5
BRDA:28,3,1,3
BRF:6
BRH:5
end_of_record
```

After the run, SonarQube dashboard shows js code violations but does not populate code coverage.
[image]

Configuration in `karma.conf.js`:

```
preprocessors: {
      'tpl/*.html': 'ng-html2js',
      '!(vendor)/*.js': 'coverage'
    },

    coverageReporter: {
      // specify a common output directory
      type: 'lcov',
      dir : 'karma_target/karma-coverage'
    },
```

SonarQube version being used is `5.0.1` and js plugin verison is `2.11`

I'm guessing the issue is with relative paths, i did go through these links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702990/sonarqube-does-not-retrieve-my-javascript-coverage-from-lcov) and [here](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonar-quot-unit-test-coverage-quot-0-with-karma-coverage-lcov-Javascript-td5030247.html), tried updating SF path to relatively point to `lcov.info` file manually, all to no avail. % is still 0.

Please let me know if i'm doing anything wrong here. Console log below, all the paths being referred are correct.

```
[INFO] [13:21:32.877] Base dir: D:\Workspace\Workspace_MasterCard\Issuer_53\loyalty\aem\loyalty-aem-web\trunk\loyalty-aem-web-ui
[INFO] [13:21:32.877] Working dir: D:\Workspace\Workspace_MasterCard\Issuer_53\loyalty\aem\loyalty-aem-web\trunk\loyalty-aem-web-ui\target\sonar
[INFO] [13:21:32.886] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibs/loyalty/js
[INFO] [13:21:32.888] Test paths: src/main/content/jcr_root/etc/clientlibs/loyalty/js_test

[INFO] [13:21:34.441] Analysing D:\Workspace\Workspace_MasterCard\Issuer_53\loyalty\aem\loyalty-aem-web\trunk\loyalty-aem-web-ui\src\main\content\jcr_root\etc\clientlibs\loyalty\karma_target\lcov.info
[INFO] [13:21:34.441] 25/25 source files have been analyzed
```

Comment: Does `lcov.info` only contains these 9 lines?

Comment: nope, i've just grabbed the screenshot of first few lines

Comment: `lcov.info` should contain lines starting with DA to indicate lines which should be covered: is that the case? You could also provide a bigger part of your logs, at least lines above and below `Analysing...lcov.info`.

Comment: updated `lcov.info` file content

Comment: `lcov.info` now looks ok. It would be easier to help you if could give the full logs. If a file path cannot be resolved, a warning should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working finally. It was this vicious problem of relative paths! Issue was with location of `karma.conf.js` file relative to the target and other folders. It's all working fine now.